# Scatter plot with different labels following description in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
      x          y              label
 0 -13.173463   1.208694      A
 0 -14.901954  -9.461114      B
 0   6.605297   8.172812      A
 0   4.506407   5.138824      A
 0  -8.560553   -0.263027     C
```

I'm trying to have plots like these: https://nikkimarinsek.com/blog/7-ways-to-label-a-cluster-plot-python
Therefore, I followed the tips from there and using `facet = sns.lmplot(data=df, x='x', y='y',hue='label')` to make my plots. However, I get: `IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.`
I'm able to plot with one color only if I remove `hue='label'`, hence, I believe the error is coming from there. Do the label column should be in an specific order?

Comment: It seems an error is generated when one of the labels is only present in one row.  This looks like a bug in seaborn.

Comment: Well that makes says, how would you calculate a regression if you only have one value?

Comment: My data is bigger than 5 lines, obviously....

Comment: I would take a look at how your columns are indexed.  In the example provided the index goes from 0, 1, 2...N, whereas all your indices are 0.  Try making them sequential and let me knows what happens.

Comment: Are there any labels that occur only once?

Comment: The example at the linked blogpost clearly works. Experimenting with it shows a problem only when there is a label that appears exactly once. If you just want to show the colored points without linear regression, you could use [`sns.scattterplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html).

Comment: Yes, I've checked my data and there was a labels with a typo, and therefore showing only once. It works now. Thanks.